# what are the maximum mqtt connections supported by activemq 5.10.0

Tags: activemq-classic, scaling, mqtt, connection, transport

I want to support around 100K mqtt connections using activemq. The activemq server is rejecting connections beyond 30K. How to tune activemq to support more number of connections.
I have tried the following

> transportConnector name="mqtt" allowLinkStealing="true"
>   uri="mqtt+nio://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=100000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&transport.defaultKeepAlive=60000&transport.closeAsync=false&useQueueForAccept=false

in `activemq.xml` but of no use.
I did some unix kernel tuning for number of open file fds to 100000.
Any one solved this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to handle > 100k connections I'd recommend looking into a dedicated MQTT broker instead of a multi-protocol message broker. You can see a list of MQTT brokers at the [MQTT Github wiki](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/Server%20support).

ActiveMQ is afaik not designed for handling that much MQTT connections and is not optimized for MQTT because it's a multi-purpose Message Queue. If you want to stick with Apache software, perhaps using Apache Apollo can help although I don't know of any MQTT Apollo deployments with that size, but probably wort a try if you need a multi-protocol broker. Again, I'd recommend a dedicated MQTT broker for large amounts of MQTT connections.

You should definitely look into reactive and multi-threaded MQTT brokers if you want to handle that amount of connections and you should make sure that the MQTT broker you choose is known to work with your desired connection amount and load. [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com) for example is capable of handling >100k connections.

Full disclosure: I work for the company behind HiveMQ.

Comment: Great suggestion. For the record, I've heard of deployments and tested Apollo with that and higher and it works like a charm. A dedicated software might still be the way to go, if ActiveMQ compatibility is not a key factor.

Comment: The Solace Message Router is both a multi-protocol message broker and it supports well over 100K concurrent MQTT connections. I know this because I work for Solace

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you use [Apache Apollo](http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/) for MQTT connections when you have that number of concurrent sessions?

Apache Apollo is a sub project of ActiveMQ with the intent to make the broker scalable to a large number of connected clients. While ActiveMQ supports MQTT, it's not really optimized for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

JoramMQ (http://jorammq.com) is based on the Joram (http://joram.ow2.org) multi-protocol message broker and it supports more than 500K concurrent MQTT connections.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still trying to find a fitting MQTT broker for many connections here are my tests of multiple brokers (I should actually add ActiveMQ to the comparison). Performance is not the only thing to compare, but also clustering, monitoring, support, price. Final pick depeneds on your own needs.

Tests were conducted on a 32GB RAM, AMD 5800X, Ubuntu 18 PC.
50 000 MQTT clients connected with no ssl.
Clients subscribed to 4 channels & no messages were published.

Tests above 50k need multiple machines involved or some other tricks because of the 65k limit of outgoing sockets in the system.

Test results

- RabbitMQ: 21GB of RAM and ~4 cores.
- Mosquitto: 200Mb of RAM and ~0.05 core.
- HiveMQ: 2.1GB of RAM and ~0.05 core.
- EMQX: 1.4GB of RAM and  ~1
  core.
- VerneMQ: 1.7GB of RAM and ~0.5 core.

If pricing is OK for you - HiveMQ lookes to me like the best broker.
If you are looking for something for free - check VerneMQ.